# Report generator in Qt using webkit or QML

Tags: qt, report

in my Qt application I'd like to output PDF-reports. The reports should be slightly modifiable for a particular customer. My idea was to create PFDs using QPrinter from rendered QWebkit-view. Rendered QML could also work. Looks for me as a very easy was to create PDF-reports with very flexible layout customization (CSS/HTML or QML) and without the need to learn/introduce additional software-package into the project.

Is someone aware of such an implementation already? It should be Open-Source (free or commercial)? 
My wish-list is :-)

1. It should be able to display images preferably provided from
   client-application as QImage/QPixmal.
2. It should be able either to
   accept all variables as QMap or query values from a Postgres DB.
3. It should be either embeddable as code or linked as a library

**EDIT**
already checked:

1. [QtRPT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtrpt/files/QtRPT/) - pretty experimental and unmature. Many magics, comments in Russian in code.
2. [NCReport](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ncreport/) - Open-source code is too old, last update 2007. Doesn't compile with Qt4.8.4. New versions are provided under commercial licenses. Commercial version looks very mature, has good documentation (ca. 100p), However I'm looking for a software which renders html/QML, so we could order a HTML-developer for creating/maintaining reports.

Comment: There is a perfect report generator based on Qt. I think this what you want. Take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/ncreport

Comment: @HesamQodsi Thank you for link. However the code looks pretty old  - last update 2007. Besides, the tool seems to render own XML files, not using webkit. Using webkit/QML could provide more flexible possibilities for layout-design.

Comment: @HesamQodsi: I came across ncreport again by google-search. Seems like they stopped hosting it on SF but use own web-site: https://www.nocisoft.com/ncreport.html. It looks very mature.

Comment: [LimeReport](https://github.com/fralx/LimeReport) seems to be good; seems to get regular pull requests/commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there is something ready made exists, otherwise it would be well known, because an issue itself pretty common. As a previous answer I also wrote my own generator. It's not open source, thought.

Problem is not only in printing (as being mentioned in previous answer). It can be more or less solved as soon as you can split whole report into pages yourself. Then you can render report content with headers/footers/page numbers/etc on 'per page' basis and print them separately.

Main problem is that it's easier up to me (having in mind all options Qt provides) to develop nice report generator for particular software, rather then trying to develop something very generic. In this case you have to either limit yourself on features you can use in the report OR introduce a lot of 'magics', certain assumptions/conventions etc.

You can make some kind of generic code for some cases then your reports all have similar structure (for example - header - first page header - main table section- footer with page numbering and all other pages the same without first page header), and then it's fairly simple to make an algorithm which will nicely split you main table section into pages.. but it's all gone as soon as you start think about more complicated scenarios with graphs etc.

An engine I've done based on JS and operates using basic reports primitives (like table, graph, label) which have some layout properties and actually JS code places them on a final report. Some reports primitives can be automatically splitter between pages some not..

Comment: +1: Thank you for sharing your experience. I wonder, what was your reason to write your own report generator?

Comment: Well, I needed it as a part of a system I am working on =)

Comment: In more details system I am developing has pretty extensive financial part which requires a lot of different reports to be generated

Answer (score 2):

I have made that kind of report generator using QWebKit (Qt version 5.1). It is not open source, though.

The biggest problem is that WebKit (or any browser's layout engine that I tried) does not work very well with printing. CSS standard covers printing, but the layout engines do not implement that stuff, or implement it only partially. So if you want features like headers and footers, page numbers, support for multiple paper sizes and support for both landscape and portrait, you have to do a lot of googling and testing. Almost nothing works as expected, so workarounds need to be invented and ugly hardcoding done.

So you *can* make a report generator using QWebKit. It's not going to be fun and new versions of Qt and QWebKit will most probably break something. So I would recommend making the report generator a separate application so that you can use different Qt versions for the main application and the report generator. At least design the report generator so, that you can separate it from the main application later if needed.

Comment: +1: Thank you! Interesting insights.